# Problem with AndroidManifest.xml file

Tags: android, android-manifest

I'm new to Android development, and I am trying to get familiar with it with some tutorials from developer.android.com. I'm working on the [`TabLayout` example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html), and I'm doing everything in the example. However, when I run it through the emulator, the program loads but when I try to start the application it says that was happened a problem and attends me to force down! Because I followed the tutorial step by step, I believe that I have made a mistake in the AndroidManifest file. Here is what I wrote:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".HelloTabWidget" android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    <activity android:name=".ArtistsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"       > </activity>
 <activity android:name=".AlbumsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"          > </activity>
 <activity android:name=".SongsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"          > </activity>
</activity>
```

can anybody help me to run this??its very important for me to learn as i m a computer eng university student and my thesis will be an application for android!!thanks a lot for your time!!

Comment: Please include the traceback your app should have printed to logcat when it force-closed. It'll be pretty hard to diagnose problems without it.

Comment: it says: "sorry!the application HelloTabWidget(process com.example.HelloTabWidget) has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again."and then has the button :force close

Comment: That's not the traceback.  That's an error message.  A traceback should say exactly which line(s) of code failed.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared your other activities inside your main activity block - make sure you close the first activity before declaring the others. See my additions below:

```
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".HelloTabWidget" android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
         </activity> <!-- ADD THIS CLOSE TAG -->

     <activity android:name=".ArtistsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name></activity>
     <activity android:name=".AlbumsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
     <activity android:name=".SongsActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"></activity>
   </application> <!-- PLUS, close your application tag -->
```

Comment: this is a very logical answer but the eclipse console says :[2010-11-22 20:01:33 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read C:\Users\kostas\android\HelloTabWidget\AndroidManifest.xml: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource is out of sync with the file system: '/HelloTabWidget/AndroidManifest.xml'.

Comment: Make sure you refresh your project (click your project and then F5).  Also, you may need to rebuild it (click the projects file menu, then clean).

Comment: thanks very much!!!i done clean and now it runs!!!thanks you very much!!can you please explain me what cleans do in order to use it in the future??thanks again!!

Comment: Sure, everytime you make a change to your code or resources, Eclipse auto-compiles.  Sometimes, your code gets in a partially built state.  When you clean your project, it forces Eclipse to recompile everything.  Also, if my answer was helpful, consider accepting it/upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

you can see some useful information and locate the problem looking at the logcat view in eclipse (and in adb logcat). Can you post the exception that occurs when you try to launch your program ?

Comment: [2010-11-22 19:38:34 - HelloTabWidget] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-11-22 19:38:34 - HelloTabWidget] Uploading HelloTabWidget.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2010-11-22 19:38:34 - HelloTabWidget] Installing HelloTabWidget.apk...
[2010-11-22 19:38:46 - HelloTabWidget] Success!
[2010-11-22 19:38:46 - HelloTabWidget] Starting activity com.example.HelloTabWidget.HelloTabWidget on device emulator-5554

Comment: [2010-11-22 19:38:48 - HelloTabWidget] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { action=android.intent.action.MAIN categories={android.intent.category.LAUNCHER} comp={com.example.HelloTabWidget/com.example.HelloTabWidget.HelloTabWidget} }

Comment: @kostas: That's the console output.  Not LogCat.

Comment: sorry for that mistake,i m new in and-dev.can you please tell me where is the logcat to paste it here?thanks

Comment: LogCat is a window in Eclipse, you should get familiar with it as it really helps with debugging.  In Eclipse, click window, show view->Logcat.  Also, read about the DDMS perspective - that also shows the LogCat and other helpful tools (like getting a screenshot of your device)